# Apache alias for Laravel and Lumen

Tags: php, apache, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to make an alias on my server which directs all traffic that comes into `example.com/z/` to a different directory than the rest of `example.com`, where `example.com` has a Laravel 4.2 install and `example.com/z/` has a Lumen install which runs a service.

This is my original vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName example.com
 DocumentRoot /data/user/public_html/public
 <Directory /data/user/public_html/public>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the vhost with the `/z/` alias added in:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /data/user/public_html/public
  Alias /z/ /data/user/service/public
  <Directory /data/user/service/public>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  <Directory /data/user/public_html/public>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

When a navigate to `exmaple.com/z/` I get a 403 page and in the logs this error:

```
 Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /data/user/service/public
```

And if I go to anything else under `/z/` (example: `/z/abcd`) I get a 404 page, but it looks like the Laravel 404 page instead of the Lumen 404 page.

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: Did you change the order to put the alias above the other VirtualHost? Not 100% confident in this working, but something I would try.

Comment: I checked. Does not work this way :(

Answer (score 15):

The message is telling you didn't added the option `Indexes`

```
<Directory /data/user/service/public>
   Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Your alias probably will have to be

```
Alias /z /data/user/service/public
```

or

```
Alias /z/ /data/user/service/public/
```

Comment: When I add this I get the directory listing (in my case index.php and test.php). Trying to navigate to either of these files results in a 404 page.

Comment: `script '/data/user/service/publicindex.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://example.com/z/`

Comment: Note that it is merging it `/.../publicindex.php` and it should be  `/data/user/service/public/index.php`

Comment: I was thinking that was the issue and changed it accordingly, which both got rid of the directory listing and made navigating to `test.php` work. Now I'm running into the issue of `example.com/z/` is returning a 404 from what looks like Lumen, but `example.com/z/test` (a route which is set up to just return 'test') is 404ing in what looks to be Laravel. Ideas on what's going on now? This is similar behavior to what I was running into originally with no trailing slash on the alias.

Comment: It's also worth noting that I've tried both variations of the alias you posted (both with and without trailing slash) with the same result either way.

Comment: Both `/z/index.php` and `/z/index.php/test` 404. But `/z/test.php` (a separate file in the public directory) works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76567/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-samsquanch).

Comment: `AllowOverride All` is what I was missing that made the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Directory index forbidden by Options directive:  /data/user/service/public

Apache has not found file specified by `DirectoryIndex` - default to `index.php` `index.html` and cannot show `indexes` follow you're configuration
Are you sure there is one of this files present in `/data/user/service/public` ?

Be sure of this and add and `.htaccess` into you're public directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

from http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls

or add a directory block to parent level (if there is some symb link)

```
  <Directory /data/user>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but adding `Require all granted` should remove some of the sharing restrictions.

The other thing to consider is ensuring your folder is actually owned by Apache's owner (www-data, apache, or even your username or something else depending on your installation). If the folder can't be read by Apache, it will trigger an error.

I also switched the Directory to refer to the Alias rather than the file path.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /data/user/public_html/public
  Alias /z /data/user/service/public
  <Directory /z>
   Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory /data/user/public_html/public>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```